# Get keyboard input without a text field/view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm making an iPhone application that has my own custom text view that can display multi-formatted text and I need to interact with the keyboard somehow. Right now I am using a hidden UITextField and the delegate method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` to get the typed characters. However this feels kludgy and I was wondering if it's possible to show the keyboard and get notified of each key tap without using a UITextField or UITextView?

Thanks,

Kyle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the public API, the best you can do is as you described. `UIKeyboard` and `UIKeyboardImpl` are both private unfortunately.

Comment: I agree.  I implemented something similar to Kyle's after not finding a better way.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that. I guess I'll go with a hidden text field.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation for the [UIKeyInput protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKeyInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) says the following:

> A subclass of UIResponder can adopt this protocol to implement simple text entry. When instances of this subclass are the first responder, the system keyboard is displayed.
>
> Only a small subset of the available keyboards and languages are available to classes that adopt this protocol.

So this might serve your needs better than a hidden text field/view.